# Process Builder error..How can we debug that

Tags: process-builder

I am getting below error when trying to update one value on opporunity. Could you pleaes help how to debug that.

```
Full Error
We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.
Flow Details
Flow Name: OB_NotificationOfMAXXNumber
Type: Workflow
Version: 1
Status: Active
Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: OB_NotificationOfMAXXNumber-7_Opportunity
Current User: David Mycka
Start time: 8/10/2016 5:28 PM
Duration: 0 seconds
How the Interview Started
Melissa Stadley (005d0000004PlCu) started the flow interview.
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
myVariable_old = 0061700000BZpVeAAL
myVariable_current = 0061700000BZpVeAAL
ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!Flow.CurrentDateTime}
Result
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "8/10/2016 5:28 PM"
DECISION: isChangedDecision2_myRule_1_OB_Group_Number_c
Executed this outcome: isChangedRule_2_myRule_1_OB_Group_Number_c
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!myVariable_old} (0061700000BZpVeAAL) Is null false
2. {!myVariable_old.OB_Group_Number__c} (null) Does not equal {!myVariable_current.OB_Group_Number__c} (99887766554)
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
DECISION: myDecision
Executed this outcome: myRule_1
Outcome conditions: 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 8 AND (4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7)
1. {!myVariable_current.RecordType.DeveloperName} (Standard_RFP) Equals Standard_RFP
2. {!myVariable_current.Type} (New Business) Equals New Business
3. {!isChangedRule_2_myRule_1_OB_Group_Number_c} (true) Equals true
4. {!myVariable_current.Office__c} (Mid America) Equals Minneapolis
5. {!myVariable_current.Office__c} (Mid America) Equals Chicago
6. {!myVariable_current.Office__c} (Mid America) Equals Mid America
7. {!myVariable_current.Office__c} (Mid America) Equals Cleveland
8. {!myVariable_current.OB_Group_Number__c} (99887766554) Is null false
Logic: Advanced Logic (1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 8 AND (4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7))
```

Comment: can you format this question, it is unreadable

Comment: What is the error message you received?  The one you posted in your question is from the debug logs?

Comment: These are the from  email which i recieved

Comment: Flow Name: OB_NotificationOfMAXXNumber
Type: Workflow
Version: 1
Status: Active

Comment: Could you post the whole email report sent by Salesforce for process failure?

Comment: @salesforcemarty, I have updated the full email. Its clear form email which flow is creating but how can i debug that.